# browserHistory.push('/test') Can't jump?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why does the button onClick function work?

Why does {this.test.bind(this)} not work?

If you click on the button button events can be normal and jump back

{this.test.bind(this)} doesn't work.

If you use the {this.test()} it works, but there will be some error

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as authActions from "../../actions/auth";
import {LoginForm} from "../../components";

@connect(
    state => ({
        user: state.async.user,
        userState: state.async.loadState && state.async.loadState.user
    }),
    authActions
)
class Login extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        user: PropTypes.any,
        userState: PropTypes.any,
        login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    test() {
        browserHistory.push('/test');
    }

    render() {
        const {user, userState, login} = this.props;
        require('./Login.scss');
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>test</button>
                {this.test.bind(this)}
                <LoginForm onSubmit={login}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: You trying to redirect until render of your component not ended. For what?

Comment: If you need to redirect until your component have setted you can try to use componentWillMount

Comment: if using componentWillMount componentDidUpdate，According to the state.async.user data to determine after log in successfully, can jump, but back when input the wrong user information state. state.async.user Value does not change, it is necessary to change back again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`{this.test.bind(this)}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a new function and isn't actually executing the function.

The button works because when the button is pressed the `onClick` function will be executed.

`this.test()` throws that warning because render will be executed multiple times for any component.

If you are attempting to navigate to `/test` when the component mounts then you should use the [React lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) `componentDidMount()`

If not, you should remove `{this.test.bind(this)}` from your component.